# Tor relay giving false HSDir flag

Tags: onion-services, relays, torproject.org

Today my tor relay started reporting the HSDir flag out of nowhere. I do not have a hidden service configured. Is this something i should worry about? Everything looks fine, and i see no services runing that shouldnt be. As far as i can tell tor hasnt created any hs certs or hostname file. Is this just some sort of glitch?

https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/D43AD758ABFB247CF326AC19D709C959E066CEFB

Answer (score 0):

Ok now ot dissapeared. Not sure what the issue was or still is.

Having the HSDir flag has nothing to do with whet...

https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/93isp3/tor_relay_giving_false_hsdir_flag/e3dlgso?utm_source=reddit-android

Answer (score 0):

Your relay can have flags such as fast, HSDir, Guard, etc by default if it has good bandwidth and sufficient active duration.

It can not become exit by default.